# Serialized neural network size in Torch after splitting layers

Tags: serialization, lua, neural-network, torch

After training a neural network, let's say a Multi-Layer Perceptron, at prediction time I want to split the first layer from all the others.
To do so, the only way I found in order to have files of the correct size, is the following:

I loop through all the layers and I add them to one of two containers (`first layer` or `all the others`) that I'll save separetelly using `torch.save` function. The funny bit is that I need to retrieve the parameters of each layer before adding them to any of the two containers, otherwise when saved, both files (`first layer` and `all the other layers`) have the same file size.

A code snippet will be more helpfull than all my previous explanation:

```
local function split_model(network)
    -- for some reason all the models when saved have the same size
    -- if not splitted calling 'getParameters()' first.
    first_layer = nn.Sequential()
    all_the_rest = nn.Sequential()
    for i = 1, network:size() do
        local l = network:get(i)
        local l_params, _ = l:getParameters()
        if i == 1 then  
            first_layer:add(l)
        else
            all_the_rest:add(l)
        end
    end
    return first_layer, all_the_rest
end

local first_layer, all_the_rest = split_model(network)
torch.save("checkpoints/mlp.t7", .network)
torch.save("checkpoints/first_layer.t7", first_layer)
torch.save("checkpoints/all_the_rest.t7", all_the_rest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same question posted in [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum%2Ftorch7#!topic/torch7/7r_C7IWfRC4), this is the answer by Alban Desmaison:

> Hi,
>
> The reason for this behavior is due to the way `getParameters` work
>   https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/module.md#flatparameters-flatgradparameters-getparameters
>   To be able to return a flat tensor containing all the parameters, it
>   actually creates a single Storage containing all the weights and then
>   each module's weight is part of this storage. When you save the
>   weights of any element of the network, it will have to save the weight
>   tensor and to do so, save the underlying storage. Hence, if you called
>   `getParameters` on the complete network, if you save any module, you
>   will save all the networks weights. Here, when you call
>   `getParameters` on the single module, it actually re-create this
>   single storage but for this single module, thus, when you save it, it
>   contains only the weights that you want. BUT note that the flattened
>   parameters returned by the `getParameters` that you did on the
>   complete network are not valid anymore!!!
>
> You have two solutions here:
>     - If you don't want to use the params coming from the `getParameters` on the complete network, you can just call
>   `getParameters` on each subset of your network before saving them.
>   This will break change the underlying storage to only contain this
>   subset of the network and you will save only what you need (shared
>   storages are stored only once).
>     - If you want to be able to keep using the params from the original `getParameters`, you can do the same as above but use cloned version
>   of them to do the `getParameters` and saving.
>
> And because a code snippet is always better:

```
require 'nn'

local subset1 = nn.Linear(2,2)
local subset2 = nn.Linear(2,2)

local network = nn.Sequential():add(subset1):add(subset2)

print("Before getParameters:", subset1.weight:storage():size()) -- 4 elements
network_params,_ = network:getParameters()
print("After getParameters:", subset1.weight:storage():size()) -- 12 elements
subset1.weight:random() -- Change weights to see if linking is still working
print("network_params is valid?", network_params[1] == subset1.weight[1][1]) -- true

-- Keeping network_params valid
local clone_subset1 = subset1:clone()
print("Cloned subset1 before getParameters:", clone_subset1.weight:storage():size()) -- 12 elements
clone_subset1:getParameters()
print("Cloned subset1 after getParameters:", clone_subset1.weight:storage():size()) -- 6 elements (4 weights + 2 bias)
subset1.weight:random() -- Change weights to see if linking is still working
print("network_params is valid?", network_params[1] == subset1.weight[1][1]) -- true

-- Not keeping network_params valid (should be faster)
local clone_subset1 = subset1:clone()
print("subset1 before getParameters:", subset1.weight:storage():size()) -- 12 elements
subset1:getParameters()
print("subset1 after getParameters:", subset1.weight:storage():size()) -- 6 elements (4 weights + 2 bias)
subset1.weight:random() -- Change weights to see if linking is still working
print("network_params is valid?", network_params[1] == subset1.weight[1][1]) -- false
```